# How can I use function getPublicFields with populate mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is the function getPublicFields in User Schema

**User Schema**

```
 
 UserSchema.methods.getPublicFields = function () {
  var returnObject = {
    firstName: this.firstName,
    lastName: this.lastName,
    email: this.email,
    _id: this._id,
  };

  return returnObject;
};
```

here just I connect the User Schema with the product and they gave me all the user Data watch I don't want

**productController.Js**

```
exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find().populate("owner");
    res.status(200).send(products);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

**Product Schema**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var { Schema } = mongoose;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  owner: {
    ref: "User",
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  img: {
    type : Array,
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Comment: You are using ```find``` you need to pass filter object as parameter otherwise it will give all the data stored in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

`populate` will give you a plain object, not a Mongoose instance. What you can do is construct a User instance from it:

```
const user = new User(product.owner);
product.owner = user.getPublicFields();
```

Comment: unfortunately is not working 100% still there is some issue

Comment: do you mind elaborate on what issue you got? Is it still complaining about the method being `undefined`?

Comment: No.. its not "undefined" , in my function getPublicFields I don't have token and user role Field as you see, so I get the data I want but I still have TOKEN and USER ROLE with it , then still there is a problem for some reason not working 100% still there is some issue

Comment: Do you mind posting the full code snippet here? It's quite difficult to know what's the issue without seeing the code